# Touch events, not limited to a specific view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, touch

How can I use touch events not limited to a specific view? I want to use those events for an background app and found out that I only can enable touch events for a view by using  `setAcceptsTouchEvents:`

Thanks in advance,
Philip

Comment: What do you mean by "background app"? Should your app receive touch events while another app is in the foreground or the user is looking at the homescreen or some system app? If so, this would most definitely not work...

Comment: An app which has no window. Toastor, do you mean an App for iOS? I mean Mac OS X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try overriding the application's `sendEvent:` method, but I doubt that will work, as it's for events within your own application. For an application that's always in the background, you won't get any such events.

The usual solution would be to install a CGEventTap, but since Quartz Event Services doesn't have event constants for touches, swipes, etc., I don't think you can do that.

The only other way I can think of might be to go through I/O Kit's HID layer; I have no idea specifically what you'll have to do to use that.

You probably should file an enhancement request in [RadarWeb](https://bugreport.apple.com/) to ask for a higher-level solution (such as touch event support in CGEventTap).

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your answer. But how's that made in the Chinese handwriting input in Snow Leopard?